# How do I set the Environment variables for Jython?

Tags: java, windows, environment-variables, jython

I have set the variables `JYTHON_HOME` to the directory where I have installed Jython and `JYTHON_PATH` to the bin folder, but I still get the following error when I try to run jython:

```
'jython' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

Why do I get this error? The Java installation has no issues.

Comment: Just add `%JYTHON_HOME\bin%` to your `PATH`. Open new Terminal and type `jython`, it will work.

Answer (score 8):

I am Windows user & I have installed Jython in `C:\jython2.7.0`.

#### What I had before?

I had neither set the `JYTHON_HOME` environment variable nor added `%JYTHON_HOME%\bin` to `PATH` environment variable. I also got the same error as shown in the question.

#### How I fixed?

- I created new environment variable named `JYTHON_HOME` with value `C:\jython2.7.0`.

> You've to use your own Jython's installation folder.

[image]

- Then I added `%JYTHON_HOME%\bin` to `PATH` environment variable as the below 2 image shows.

> Create new **PATH** environment variable if it is not already there (This is rare case).

[image]

- Open new Terminal and type `jython`, it will work. Now you can try executing simple Python statements as the below image shows.

> Do not use the already opened Terminal.

[image]

That's it.

Answer (score 5):

You still need to add the path to the executable jython.bat to your PATH environment variable. Here as an example I'm providing my ini-jython.bat, which I use before executing my jython project (in this case it's a Django on Jython project, you can safely ignore the Django stuff, or adapt it to your needs):

```
set JYTHON_HOME=c:\tools\jython2.5.2
set PATH=%JYTHON_HOME%\bin;%PATH%
set CLASSPATH=dep1;dep1/lib/*;_lib/*
set JYTHONPATH=.;..\django-debug-toolbar;..\django-common
set DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=site_projname.settings
set PYTHONPATH=%JYTHONPATH%
set manage=jython c:\tools\jython2.5.2\bin\django-admin.py
set makemessages=django-admin makemessages --extension html,py
set compilemessages=django-admin compilemessages
```

Comment: Thank Sirs. Could you please give me clear idea about jython.bat path

Comment: The PATH system variable indicates where the system can look for executables. jython.bat is the jython executable, it should be inside the directory in which you've installed jython, in the "/bin/" subfolder. For example if you've installed jython in "c:\tools\jython", you'll need to modify your path environment variable to include "c:\tools\jython\bin". You'd achieve this by executing: "SET PATH=c:\tools\jython\bin;%PATH%" . With this sentence you're asking the system to modify the PATH variable to include the jython bin folder followed by the existing contents of the PATH variable (%PATH%).